# When presenting Touch ID prompt, is it possible to immediately offer the user the chance to enter their passcode?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios9, touch-id

When presenting Touch ID / Local Authentication to unlock something, and both Touch ID and Passcode are possible, it will only show the "Enter Password" option *after* the first attempt at Touch ID fails.

Is it possible to show it right away? I'm envisioning a user who isn't authenticated to use Touch ID on the device tries to use the app, and if they know the passcode it's totally okay to be using it, and they may not try their finger print as they know it's not added.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? With FaceID it's even (much) more annoying...

Comment: Have you tried removing `NSFaceIDUsageDescription` from info.plist? In my tests this will make iOS ignore faceid and present the passcode dialog immediately. But only, if you never allowed faceid before. If you did, you need to remove faceid access in settings

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible Touch ID with Passcode

- Works with Apple Face ID (iPhone X, Xs, XR, XsMax) and other Touch ID having devices.
- Predefined error handling when recognition fails.
- Automatic authentication with device passcode on multiple failed attempts.

Use Apple FaceID or TouchID authentication in your app using BiometricAuthentication. It's very simple and easy to use that handles Touch ID and Face ID authentication based on the device.

Please check this example :-

- [Apple Touch ID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id)

Two option's available

- .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
- deviceOwnerAuthentication

  ```
  extension ViewController {

  func authenticationWithTouchID() {
   let localAuthenticationContext = LAContext()
   localAuthenticationContext.localizedFallbackTitle = "Use Passcode"

   var authError: NSError?
   let reasonString = "To access the secure data"

   if localAuthenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &authError) {

       localAuthenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reasonString) { success, evaluateError in

           if success {
               print("User authenticated successfully")
               //TODO: User authenticated successfully, take appropriate action

           } else {
               //TODO: User did not authenticate successfully, look at error and take appropriate action
               guard let error = evaluateError else {
                   return
               }

               print(self.evaluateAuthenticationPolicyMessageForLA(errorCode: error._code))

               //TODO: If you have choosen the 'Fallback authentication mechanism selected' (LAError.userFallback). Handle gracefully

           }
       }
   } else {

       guard let error = authError else {
           return
       }
       //TODO: Show appropriate alert if biometry/TouchID/FaceID is lockout or not enrolled
       print(self.evaluateAuthenticationPolicyMessageForLA(errorCode: error.code))
   }
  }

  func evaluatePolicyFailErrorMessageForLA(errorCode: Int) -> String {
   var message = ""
   if #available(iOS 11.0, macOS 10.13, *) {
       switch errorCode {
           case LAError.biometryNotAvailable.rawValue:
               message = "Authentication could not start because the device does not support biometric authentication."

           case LAError.biometryLockout.rawValue:
               message = "Authentication could not continue because the user has been locked out of biometric authentication, due to failing authentication too many times."

           case LAError.biometryNotEnrolled.rawValue:
               message = "Authentication could not start because the user has not enrolled in biometric authentication."

           default:
               message = "Did not find error code on LAError object"
       }
   } else {
       switch errorCode {
           case LAError.touchIDLockout.rawValue:
               message = "Too many failed attempts."

           case LAError.touchIDNotAvailable.rawValue:
               message = "TouchID is not available on the device"

           case LAError.touchIDNotEnrolled.rawValue:
               message = "TouchID is not enrolled on the device"

           default:
               message = "Did not find error code on LAError object"
       }
   }

   return message;
  }

  func evaluateAuthenticationPolicyMessageForLA(errorCode: Int) -> String {

   var message = ""

   switch errorCode {

   case LAError.authenticationFailed.rawValue:
       message = "The user failed to provide valid credentials"

   case LAError.appCancel.rawValue:
       message = "Authentication was cancelled by application"

   case LAError.invalidContext.rawValue:
       message = "The context is invalid"

   case LAError.notInteractive.rawValue:
       message = "Not interactive"

   case LAError.passcodeNotSet.rawValue:
       message = "Passcode is not set on the device"

   case LAError.systemCancel.rawValue:
       message = "Authentication was cancelled by the system"

   case LAError.userCancel.rawValue:
       message = "The user did cancel"

   case LAError.userFallback.rawValue:
       message = "The user chose to use the fallback"

   default:
       message = evaluatePolicyFailErrorMessageForLA(errorCode: errorCode)
   }

   return message
   }
  }
  ```

[image: Note:-Video converted to gif image. this example in passcode enter screen in keyboard not showing because it's recording.]

Comment: how do these examples show an IMMEDIATE possibility of passcode entry?

Comment: yes but you can change .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics to deviceOwnerAuthentication than run app wrong touch id after choose to use passcode and open the enter passcode screen.

Comment: but that's the question; if it's possible to show the passcode IMMEDIATELY, without first going through (failing) biometrics

Comment: you can remove finger print all and than check direct open passcode screen.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id

in this demo run in my iphone finger remove after direct open passcode screen.